# Why won't my input-text box expand to a width larger than 64px while still staying on the same line (nav bar)

Tags: html, css

This is the CSS and HTML for the nav bar which goes:

> menu icon (#image), then main text (.red), then search icon (#search), and the search bar that won't stay up, (input [type=text].

My problem is that the search bar won't stay with the rest of the items despite it still having tons of space. It doesn't want to expand to a width larger than 64.2px and then it decides to stay under the rest of the items.

I've tried all sorts of displays and widths, but this is the only one that keeps it on top and it's too small in my opinion.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1-0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>RED Info Sheet</title>
    <style>
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            float: left;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        input[type=text] {
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            margin: 28px 0 0 0;
            font-family: bebas neue;
            width: 30%;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        /* this is the css the text box follows */ 
        .nav {
            background-color: #db1f1f;
            color: black;
            display: flex;
            positiion: fixed;
            top: 0;
            font-family: Bebas Neue;
            align-items: center;
            width: 100%;
            float: left;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        /* This is the css for the nav */
        .red {
            background-color: #db1f1f;
            color: black;
            display: inline-block;
            font-family: Bebas Neue;
            float: left;
            width: 60%;
            padding: 10px 0px 0 20px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 55px;
            margin: 0 0 0 10px;
        }
        /* This one (.red) appears before the search photo and text box */
        #image {
            width: 60px;
            height: 100%;
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 100px 0 0 4ox;
        }
        /* menu icon */
        #search {
            width: 7%;
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            margin: 25px 10px 0 10px;
            padding: 0 0 0 0;
            position: relative;
        }
        /* search image magnifying glass icon everything else after this point is
           just part of a dropdown list which i don't think is relevant to the problem */ 
        #image:hover {
            background-color: white;
        }
        .dropbtn {
            display: inline-block;
            color: black;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 5px 5px;
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: #db1f1f;
            width: 100%;
        }
        li a:hover,
        .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
            background-color: #db1f1f;
            color: white;
            text-decoration: underline;
            padding: 5px 5px;
        }
        li.dropdown {
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            width: 10%;
        }
        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #c9cdd4;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            z-index: 1;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        .dropdown-content a {
            color: black;
            padding: 1px 1px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            text-align: left;
        }
        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <div class="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#si">
                                <img class="dropbtn" id="image" src="https://assets.stickpng.com/images/588a6507d06f6719692a2d15.png"
                                    alt="menu-icon">
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-content">
                                <a href="#home">Home</a>
                                <br>
                                <a href="#mv">Music and Lyric Videos</a>
                                <br>
                                <a href="#info">Information</a>
                                <br>
                                <a href="#perf">Performances</a>
                                <br>
                                <a href="#photos">Photos</a>
                                <br>
                                <a href="#si">Song Info</a>
                                <br>
                        </li>
                        </div>
                        <li class="red">Red Taylor Swift</li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/61/61088.png" alt="magnifying- 
glass" id="search">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

Comment: Your styles have an Input type[text] with a width set to 30%. Is this restricting its size? Set it to 100%

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know what style you want, but I tried to make some modifications. Do you want this Style?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1-0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>RED Info Sheet</title>
    <style>
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            float: left;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            flex-grow: 1;
        }

        input[type=text] {
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            margin: 28px 0 0 0;
            font-family: bebas neue;
            width: 30%;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .nav {
            background-color: #db1f1f;
            color: black;
            display: flex;
            positiion: fixed;
            top: 0;
            font-family: Bebas Neue;
            align-items: center;
            width: 100%;
            float: left;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .red {
            background-color: #db1f1f;
            color: black;
            display: inline-block;
            font-family: Bebas Neue;

            float: left;
            /* width: 60%; */
            padding: 10px 0px 0 20px;
            text-align: center;

            font-size: 55px;
            margin: 0 0 0 10px;
        }

        #image {
            width: 60px;
            height: 100%;
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 100px 0 0 4ox;

        }

        #search {
            width: 40px;
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            margin: 25px 10px 0 10px;
            padding: 0 0 0 0;
            position: relative;
        }

        #image:hover {
            background-color: white;
        }

        .dropbtn {
            display: inline-block;
            color: black;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 5px 5px;
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: #db1f1f;
            width: 100%;
        }


        li a:hover,
        .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
            background-color: #db1f1f;
            color: white;
            text-decoration: underline;

            padding: 5px 5px;
        }

        li.dropdown {
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            width: 10%;

        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #c9cdd4;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            z-index: 1;
            font-size: 20px;

        }

        .dropdown-content a {
            color: black;
            padding: 1px 1px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;
        }


        /* 
        
        

         */
        ul>li {
            float: left;

        }

        ul>li:last-child {
            width: 30%;
        }

        input[type=text] {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .fixedWidth {
            width: 65px !important;
        }

        body,
        html {
            border: 0;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="dropdown fixedWidth">
                <div class="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#si"><img class="dropbtn" id="image"
                                    src="https://assets.stickpng.com/images/588a6507d06f6719692a2d15.png"
                                    alt="menu-icon"></a>
                            <div class="dropdown-content">
                                <a href="#home">Home</a><br>
                                <a href="#mv">Music and Lyric Videos</a><br>
                                <a href="#info">Information</a><br>
                                <a href="#perf">Performances</a><br>
                                <a href="#photos">Photos</a><br>
                                <a href="#si">Song Info</a><br>
                        </li>
                </div>
            <li class="red">Red Taylor Swift</li>
            <li><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/61/61088.png" alt="magnifying- 
glass" id="search"></li>
            <li><input type="text" placeholder="Search..."></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```